# Convert Composed Type in Golang

Tags: go

I've been [reading about](https://attilaolah.eu/2014/09/10/json-and-struct-composition-in-go/) type alias and composed structs in Golang. I want to be able to have two structs which are structurally identical but can be easily converted between each other.

I have a parent structure defined as:

```
type User struct {
    Email    string `json:"email"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
}
```

And a composed struct defined as:

```
type PublicUser struct {
    *User
}
```

I would expect that if I define a `User`:

```
a := User{
        Email:    "admin@example.net",
        Password: "1234",
    }
```

I could then perform the following type conversion:

```
b := (a).(PublicUser)
```

But it fails with an invalid type assertion:

```
invalid type assertion: a.(PublicUser) (non-interface type User on left)
```

How can I convert between structurally similar types in Go?

https://play.golang.org/p/I0VqrflOfXU

Comment: "I have a parent strucutre defined". No you don't. There is _no_ parent/child relation on Go. Forget that now and forever. Thinking about compositions as parent/child is not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type assertions in Go let you tap into an *interface's* concrete type, not into structs:

> A type assertion provides access to an interface value's underlying concrete value.
>   https://tour.golang.org/methods/15

However, with slight modifications, this code works and probably behaves as you would expect:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type User struct {
    Email    string `json:"email"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
}

type PublicUser User

func main() {
    a := User{
        Email:    "admin@example.net",
        Password: "1234",
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", a)
    // out: User{Email:"admin@example.net", Password:"1234"}

    b := PublicUser(a)
    fmt.Printf("%#v", b)
    // out PublicUser{Email:"admin@example.net", Password:"1234"}
}
```

Here, `PublicUser` is a redefinition of the `User` type; most importantly, it is a standalone type, shares the fields, but not the method set of User (https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions).

Then, you can simply use the PublicUser type constructor, as you might have been doing similarly with `string`/`[]byte` conversions: `foo := []byte("foobar")`.

If, on the other hand, you were to use an actual [type alias](https://blog.golang.org/go1.9) (`type PublicUser = User`) your output will list `User` as type for both instances: PublicUser is only a new name for the old thing, not a new type.